# How can i achieve this effect in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

[image]

How can i achieve this effect in After Effects?

Comment: What did you try and what issues are you having? You'll have more chances of solving your issue if you ask a specific question than simply request a tutorial. I also recommend that you read this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use time displacement maps and the effect you are searching for is "slit scan".

Here is a video explaining it: 
https://lesterbanks.com/2013/08/creating-a-slit-scan-effect-in-after-effects-using-time-displacement/